# DAX Unique Balance Aggreagation

Tags: dax

How can I formulate a DAX calculation where the year total, is not the SUM, but the amount latest in the year, ie. If have data as below, the GrandTotal/Year total would be: `-3416261278` not what appears:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ISFILTERED(<columnName>)` in your measure.

If `ISFILTERED(date[date])` is TRUE the measure will be evaluating a cell. If FALSE then it'll be evaluating the Grand Total.

Example:

```
LastNonZeroMeasure:=IF( [TotalValue] = 0 || NOT(  ISFILTERED ( 'date'[date] )  ),
    CALCULATE (
        [TotalValue],
        TOPN(
            1,
            CALCULATETABLE(
                'value',
                FILTER(
                    ALL( 'value' ),
                    [TotalValue] > 0
                ),
                FILTER(
                    ALL( 'date' ),
                    'date'[date] < max( 'date'[date] )
                )
            ),
            'value'[date],
            DESC
        )
    ),
    [TotalValue]
)
```

[image]